# set directional-scss variable at build time

Tags: angular, sass, angular-i18n

i'm using angular to build multi language system, with angular i18n for internalization I have to build each language as a different package. Since some of the languages are RTL, i'm using directional scss (instead of importing different stylesheets or applying `class=rtl` on elements).

The issue is, that I don't want to change code before each build. I need to change just one simple line in scss variables file: 
`$dir = ltr` to `$dir = rtl` on RTL languages.

Is it possible to extract this value from the build script or something ? that would create much smoother build process.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution/workaround to this.

- In `angular-cli.json` I defined 2 apps: ltr and rtl.
- under styles, each app compiles 2 different files:

  - `directional-scss.scss` and `directional-scss-rtl.scss` - with the 
    `$dir` variable set to the correct value.
  - `style-ltr.scss` and `style-rtl.scss` - basically they are the same, but each one imports the correct directional-scss file.
- In my `package.json` file, I added a script to build all: `"build-all": "npm-run-all --parallel build-en build-i18n:he"`
- My build scipt looks like this: `"build-en": "ng build --app=ltr --output-path=dist --aot -prod --bh / --locale=en-US"`, notice the `--app=ltr`. do the same in other languages build with the correct direction.

Thats it, I can now run this script and build both languages! or server them at the same time on different ports for dev and QA.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to modifying your build process to include a new import file defining this variable - it's not possible to access the environment variables directly from Sass code.

If you're using Webpack for example:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#environment-variables

Of course, you'll be only able to change that configuration if you're using the configs directly (not with the Angular CLI) - or if you do an `ng eject`.

Comment: thanks that's helpful, I have to learn about eject. I am using webpack with angular-cli.